# What is the recommended way to control changes of properties of an object

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, coding-style

Assume we have the following interface:

```
@interface ColoredView : NSView {
    NSColor *color;
}
@property (copy) NSColor *color;

- (id)initWithColor:(NSColor *)aColor;

@end
```

And we want view to show an animation whenever color is changed i.e. the animation should trigger just after color is changed.

The question is what is the best place to implement trigger logic: setter, observeValue or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the setter (using, e.g., notifications) if you can, otherwise using KVO. KVO is nicer in theory (very little coupling between the two classes) but can come with a few surprises.

Comment: Is that normal to use observing pattern to make an object to observe changes of its properties?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your design, yes. It might not be worth it for small projects.